# Python best practice for interacting with blocking loop via REPL

Tags: python, loops, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

My program involves a blocking loop. I'd like to use the a python REPL to modify program state while the program is running.

### Context:

Often I have a blocking loop in my python code:

```
# main.py
import itertools
import time
global_state = 123

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting main loop")
    m = 0
    for n in itertools.count():
        time.sleep(1)  # "computation"
        global_state += 1
        m += 10
        print(f"{n=}, {m=}, {global_state=}")
```

When I run this program at the command line, I get something like this:

```
$ python -i main.py
Starting main loop
n=0, m=10, global_state=124
n=1, m=20, global_state=125
n=2, m=30, global_state=126
...
```

The loop will run for hours or days. Sometimes, while the loop is running, I desire to interactively modify some program state. For example, I'd like to set `global_state = -1000` or `m = 75`. But the `loop` function is blocking...

### Approaches to interactive modification of program state

#### Approach 1: Stopping and restarting the loop

I can use a `KeyboardInterrupt` to stop the loop. Since I have invoked `python` with the `-i` interactive flag, I can then modify the global state at the interactive REPL. I then restart the loop. This is a simple approach, but it has drawbacks:

- If the loop modifies the global state (or has any side effects), the global state might be left in an inconsistent state when KeyboardInterrupt is raised; the exception could be raised at any point in the loop's control flow, and handling this exception properly can be tricky, especially if the business logic is complex.
- When restarting the loop, the counter `n` will be reset to zero. Other state variables used by the loop (e.g. `m`) might also be reset or be in an inconsistent state.

#### Approach 2: Using threading

I can wrap the loop in a function and use `threading` to run the function in another thread:

```
def loop():
    print("Starting main loop")
    m = 0
    for n in itertools.count():
        time.sleep(1)  # "computation"
        global_state += 1
        m += 10
        print(f"{n=}, {m=}, {global_state=}")
import threading
thread = threading.Thread(target=loop)
thread.start()
```

When I invoke `python -i main.py`, I can use the REPL to interact with global state as the loop runs in another thread. The `loop` function still `print`s to `stdout` as before. The drawbacks of this approach are:

- I can no longer interact with the loop's local state (e.g. I can't modify `m`) because the local state is wrapped in a function. This is a major drawback.
- Using threading makes the program more fragile; threads can crash, and exceptions raised in threads need to be handled carefully. If the thread blocks or crashes or hangs, it can be hard to recover.
- Stopping the loop becomes more difficult, because KeyboardInterrupt is no longer an option (instead I need to "cooperate" with the thread, sending it some signal that it should self-terminate).

#### Approach 3: Drop into REPL from within the loop

I can cooperate with the loop to drop into the repl:

```
import os
import code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    for n in itertools.count():
        ...  # business logic
        if os.stat("use_repl.txt").st_size > 0:  # file nonempty             
            code.interact(local=locals())
```

Here we are using a file to signal to the loop when we want to modify state. If the "use_repl.txt" file is nonempty then loop then calls `code.interact` to create an interactive Console. This has the added benefit of working even if the loop is wrapped in a function; local variables are loaded into the interactive console.
Drawbacks:

- Reading a "use_repl.txt" file at every pass through the loop feels a bit clunky. But how else would one signal (cooperatively) to the loop that it should create a REPL?
- The loop gets paused when `code.interact` is called. This differs from the `threading`-based solution, where the loop runs continuously. This may be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on your use-case.
- The REPL created by `code.interact` is not as polished as python's native interactive mode. For example, tab-completion no longer works.

An alternative to calling `code.interact` would be to call the `breakpoint` built-in function. Another alternative would be to invoke the `break` keyword, exiting the loop. One could then modify state and restart the loop (as in approach 1), without having to worry that a KeyboardInterrupt has created an inconsistent state.

### The Question(s):

Are there any approaches that I've missed? Each of the approaches considered has significant drawbacks... Are there any best-practices regarding achievement of the desired result?

Comment: this is pretty open ended and opinion based, but if I wanted to make it have an editable state, I would have a webserver change the state, while the workers run in threads.

Comment: That makes sense. I've shied away from using a database / server to keep track of state because, in my particular use case, it's sometimes hard to anticipate which parts of the state I will want to change. Sometimes I even change the instructions that gets executed by the loop, possibly introducing new state variables or stateful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug the program, pause it when you want to inspect/modify state, then resume.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by xaa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64509269):

```
import pdb
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, pdb.Pdb().sigint_handler)
```

This sets a signal handler catching `SIGINT` (which would otherwise get translated into `KeyboardInterrupt`), dropping into `pdb` when `CTRL-C` is pressed. Thus `CTRL-C` can be used to interrupt the loop and inspect or modify state at any point, and execution can be resumed by typing `continue` at the `pdb` prompt.